# Accessing Neo4j Enterprise remotely deployed in an azure VM

Tags: azure, neo4j, windows-firewall

I have installed Neo4j Enterprise edition 4.1.1 to our Azure VM and exposed the port in the neo4j config file as follows.

```
dbms.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=DISABLED
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7061

HTTP Connector. There can be zero or one HTTP connectors.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7062.
```

I have created two private windows firewall inbound rules,one for http and other for bolt .Unfortunately,I am not able to access the neo4j URL from my local with Azure VPN client enabled. I am using VM private IP in the URL.
Even Telnet also is not working.

Though I am able to access the URL from the VM server .

Is there anything I am missing here?Appreciate your response on this issue.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The issue was private firewall which prevent neo4j URL outside azure VM. I have made this public and it worked.

I needed to login to azure VPN client to access the URL.